# Animation for moving nodes in a graph using Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

In this [demo](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) the shapes represent the nodes, and connections represent the edges. You can drag and drop a shape. During the mousemove event the following code is called, which redraws the shape and its connections:

```
move = function (dx, dy) {
        var att = this.type == "rect" ? {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy} : {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy};
        this.attr(att);
        for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
            r.connection(connections[i]);
        }
        r.safari();
    }
```

I want to create an animation for moving a shape. While the shape is beeing moved its afferent connections should also be redrawn. The following code animates moving the shape:

```
shapes[0].animate({transform: "t100,100"}, 1000, 'bounce');
```

But I don't know how to redraw the connections during this animation. I know about the [animateWith](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animateWith) function from the Raphael library, but I'm not sure how should I use it here.
Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a data property that stores the current position on the graph and another property to track it's associated connections. Then when a change is made the the position data I would be listening for eve events and then handle the animation with the event (you would be able to get the associated connections and create the necessary animations for them as well).

Comment: I understand your point. However I've read somewhere that Eve is an  unstable API, and should be used with caution. I am hoping to find some easier workaround, but I'll try your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Well, if you'd prefer using eve isn't necessary. The only necessary part to the solution is having a reference to the afferent connections so that you can animate them. Storing those references in a property should be enough for you to make any additional animation calls necessary.